Qt Designer Scrollbars not showing up
I'm using Qt Designer to create a GUI for my application (QGIS extension). In the application, certain areas are scrollable as intended. However, in Qt Designer, scrollbars are not visible, making it impossible to rearrange or access items that are out of view.
How can I scroll within these areas in Qt Designer to see and modify the hidden items?
This screenshot shows the problem with a red arrow that represents the missing scrollbar. An example ui file code can be found below.

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>example</class>
 <widget class="QDockWidget" name="example">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>785</width>
    <height>839</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="sizePolicy">
   <sizepolicy hsizetype="Expanding" vsizetype="Expanding">
    <horstretch>0</horstretch>
    <verstretch>0</verstretch>
   </sizepolicy>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Example</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="dockWidgetContents">
   <property name="sizePolicy">
    <sizepolicy hsizetype="MinimumExpanding" vsizetype="Preferred">
     <horstretch>0</horstretch>
     <verstretch>0</verstretch>
    </sizepolicy>
   </property>
   <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout_34">
    <item>
     <widget class="QTabWidget" name="tabWidget">
      <property name="sizePolicy">
       <sizepolicy hsizetype="Expanding" vsizetype="Minimum">
        <horstretch>0</horstretch>
        <verstretch>0</verstretch>
       </sizepolicy>
      </property>
      <property name="currentIndex">
       <number>0</number>
      </property>
      <widget class="QWidget" name="OptionsTab">
       <property name="sizePolicy">
        <sizepolicy hsizetype="Preferred" vsizetype="Minimum">
         <horstretch>0</horstretch>
         <verstretch>0</verstretch>
        </sizepolicy>
       </property>
       <property name="layoutDirection">
        <enum>Qt::LeftToRight</enum>
       </property>
       <attribute name="title">
        <string>Process</string>
       </attribute>
       <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout_7">
        <property name="sizeConstraint">
         <enum>QLayout::SetDefaultConstraint</enum>
        </property>
        <property name="leftMargin">
         <number>0</number>
        </property>
        <property name="topMargin">
         <number>0</number>
        </property>
        <property name="rightMargin">
         <number>0</number>
        </property>
        <property name="bottomMargin">
         <number>0</number>
        </property>
        <item row="0" column="0">
         <widget class="QScrollArea" name="scrollArea_3">
          <property name="palette">
           <palette>
            <active>
             <colorrole role="Base">
              <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
               <color alpha="255">
                <red>255</red>
                <green>255</green>
                <blue>255</blue>
               </color>
              </brush>
             </colorrole>
             <colorrole role="Window">
              <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
               <color alpha="255">
                <red>255</red>
                <green>255</green>
                <blue>255</blue>
               </color>
              </brush>
             </colorrole>
            </active>
            <inactive>
             <colorrole role="Base">
              <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
               <color alpha="255">
                <red>255</red>
                <green>255</green>
                <blue>255</blue>
               </color>
              </brush>
             </colorrole>
             <colorrole role="Window">
              <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
               <color alpha="255">
                <red>255</red>
                <green>255</green>
                <blue>255</blue>
               </color>
              </brush>
             </colorrole>
            </inactive>
            <disabled>
             <colorrole role="Base">
              <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
               <color alpha="255">
                <red>255</red>
                <green>255</green>
                <blue>255</blue>
               </color>
              </brush>
             </colorrole>
             <colorrole role="Window">
              <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
               <color alpha="255">
                <red>255</red>
                <green>255</green>
                <blue>255</blue>
               </color>
              </brush>
             </colorrole>
            </disabled>
           </palette>
          </property>
          <property name="frameShape">
           <enum>QFrame::NoFrame</enum>
          </property>
          <property name="frameShadow">
           <enum>QFrame::Plain</enum>
          </property>
          <property name="widgetResizable">
           <bool>true</bool>
          </property>
          <widget class="QWidget" name="scrollAreaWidgetContents_4">
           <property name="geometry">
            <rect>
             <x>0</x>
             <y>0</y>
             <width>755</width>
             <height>770</height>
            </rect>
           </property>
           <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout_3">
            <item>
             <widget class="QScrollArea" name="scrollArea">
              <property name="sizePolicy">
               <sizepolicy hsizetype="Expanding" vsizetype="Minimum">
                <horstretch>0</horstretch>
                <verstretch>0</verstretch>
               </sizepolicy>
              </property>
              <property name="widgetResizable">
               <bool>true</bool>
              </property>
              <widget class="QWidget" name="scrollAreaWidgetContents">
               <property name="geometry">
                <rect>
                 <x>0</x>
                 <y>0</y>
                 <width>729</width>
                 <height>954</height>
                </rect>
               </property>
               <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout_4">
                <item row="0" column="0">
                 <widget class="QWidget" name="widget_2" native="true">
                  <property name="sizePolicy">
                   <sizepolicy hsizetype="Preferred" vsizetype="Fixed">
                    <horstretch>0</horstretch>
                    <verstretch>0</verstretch>
                   </sizepolicy>
                  </property>
                  <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout_3">
                   <property name="leftMargin">
                    <number>6</number>
                   </property>
                   <property name="topMargin">
                    <number>6</number>
                   </property>
                   <property name="rightMargin">
                    <number>6</number>
                   </property>
                   <property name="bottomMargin">
                    <number>6</number>
                   </property>
                   <item row="8" column="0">
                    <widget class="QLabel" name="label_3">
                     <property name="text">
                      <string>-S, --selection </string>
                     </property>
                    </widget>
                   </item>
                   <item row="18" column="0">
                    <widget class="QLabel" name="proj_out_label">
                     <property name="text">
                      <string>--proj-out</string>
                     </property>
                    </widget>
                   </item>
                   <item row="6" column="0">
                    <widget class="QLabel" name="label">
                     <property name="text">
                      <string>-O, --orientation</string>
                     </property>
                    </widget>
                   </item>
                   <item row="5" column="0">
                    <widget class="QComboBox" name="topology_select">
                     <item>
                      <property name="text">
                       <string>full</string>
                      </property>
                     </item>
                     <item>
                      <property name="text">
                       <string>none</string>
                      </property>
                     </item>
                     <item>
                      <property name="text">
                       <string>basic</string>
                      </property>
                     </item>
                    </widget>
                   </item>
                   <item row="14" column="0">
                    <widget class="QLabel" name="label_10">
                     <property name="text">
                      <string>-D, --dangling</string>
                     </property>
                    </widget>
                   </item>
                   <item row="12" column="0">
                    <widget class="QLabel" name="label_6">
                     <property name="text">
                      <string>-d, --decimal-places</string>
                     </property>
                    </widget>
                   </item>
                   <item row="13" column="0">
                    <widget class="QLineEdit" name="decimal_places_input">
                     <property name="text">
                      <string>3</string>
                     </property>
                     <property name="placeholderText">
                      <string>-d, --decimal-places</string>
                     </property>
                    </widget>
                   </item>
                   <item row="17" column="0">
                    <widget class="QLineEdit" name="x_offset_input">
                     <property name="text">
                      <string>0,0</string>
                     </property>
                     <property name="placeholderText">
                      <string>-x, --x-offset (default: 0,0)</string>
                     </property>
                    </widget>
                   </item>
                   <item row="10" column="0">
                    <widget class="QLabel" name="label_5">
                     <property name="text">
                      <string>-t, --tolerance</string>
                     </property>
                    </widget>
                   </item>
                   <item row="15" column="0">
                    <widget class="QLineEdit" name="dangling_input">
                     <property name="text">
                      <string>0,0</string>
                     </property>
                     <property name="placeholderText">
                      <string>-D, --dangling (default: 0,0 = off)</string>
                     </property>
                    </widget>
                   </item>
                   <item row="9" column="0">
                    <widget class="QLineEdit" name="selection_input">
                     <property name="sizePolicy">
                      <sizepolicy hsizetype="Expanding" vsizetype="Fixed">
                       <horstretch>0</horstretch>
                       <verstretch>0</verstretch>
                      </sizepolicy>
                     </property>
                     <property name="maximumSize">
                      <size>
                       <width>16777215</width>
                       <height>900</height>
                      </size>
                     </property>
                     <property name="placeholderText">
                      <string>-S, --selection (see manual for details)</string>
                     </property>
                    </widget>
                   </item>
                   <item row="19" column="0">
                    <widget class="QWidget" name="proj_out_group" native="true">
                     <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout_15">
                      <property name="leftMargin">
                       <number>0</number>
                      </property>
                      <property name="topMargin">
                       <number>0</number>
                      </property>
                      <property name="rightMargin">
                       <number>0</number>
                      </property>
                      <property name="bottomMargin">
                       <number>6</number>
                      </property>
                      <item>
                       <widget class="QLineEdit" name="proj_out_input">
                        <property name="placeholderText">
                         <string>EPSG:3857</string>
                        </property>
                       </widget>
                      </item>
                      <item>
                       <widget class="QLabel" name="label_mode">
                        <property name="text">
                         <string>--label-mode-poly</string>
                        </property>
                       </widget>
                      </item>
                      <item>
                       <widget class="QComboBox" name="label_mode_poly_select">
                        <item>
                         <property name="text">
                          <string>center</string>
                         </property>
                        </item>
                        <item>
                         <property name="text">
                          <string>first</string>
                         </property>
                        </item>
                        <item>
                         <property name="text">
                          <string>last</string>
                         </property>
                        </item>
                       </widget>
                      </item>
                      <item>
                       <widget class="QLabel" name="label_2">
                        <property name="text">
                         <string>-L, --label</string>
                        </property>
                       </widget>
                      </item>
                      <item>
                       <widget class="QLineEdit" name="label_input">
                        <property name="placeholderText">
                         <string>-L, --label (see manual for details)</string>
                        </property>
                       </widget>
                      </item>
                      <item>
                       <widget class="QLabel" name="label_4">
                        <property name="text">
                         <string>-z, --z-offset </string>
                        </property>
                       </widget>
                      </item>
                      <item>
                       <widget class="QLineEdit" name="z_offset_input">
                        <property name="text">
                         <string>0,0</string>
                        </property>
                        <property name="placeholderText">
                         <string>-z, --z-offset (default: 0,0)</string>
                        </property>
                       </widget>
                      </item>
                      <item>
                       <widget class="QLabel" name="label_12">
                        <property name="text">
                         <string>-y, --y-offset</string>
                        </property>
                       </widget>
                      </item>
                      <item>
                       <widget class="QLineEdit" name="y_offset_input">
                        <property name="text">
                         <string>0,0</string>
                        </property>
                        <property name="placeholderText">
                         <string>-y, --y-offset (default: 0,0)</string>
                        </property>
                       </widget>
                      </item>
                      <item>
                       <widget class="QLabel" name="label_9">
                        <property name="text">
                         <string>decimal group input</string>
                        </property>
                       </widget>
                      </item>
                      <item>
                       <widget class="QLineEdit" name="decimal_group_input">
                        <property name="text">
                         <string>,</string>
                        </property>
                        <property name="placeholderText">
                         <string>-g, --decimal-group (default: auto)</string>
                        </property>
                       </widget>
                      </item>
                      <item>
                       <widget class="QLabel" name="label_8">
                        <property name="text">
                         <string>decimal point input</string>
                        </property>
                       </widget>
                      </item>
                      <item>
                       <widget class="QLineEdit" name="decimal_point_input">
                        <property name="text">
                         <string>.</string>
                        </property>
                        <property name="placeholderText">
                         <string>-i, --decimal-point (default: auto)</string>
                        </property>
                       </widget>
                      </item>
                      <item>
                       <widget class="QLabel" name="label_7">
                        <property name="text">
                         <string>-s, --snapping</string>
                        </property>
                       </widget>
                      </item>
                      <item>
                       <widget class="QLineEdit" name="snapping_input">
                        <property name="text">
                         <string>0,0</string>
                        </property>
                        <property name="placeholderText">
                         <string>-s, --snapping (default: 0,0 = off)</string>
                        </property>
                       </widget>
                      </item>
                     </layout>
                    </widget>
                   </item>
                   <item row="4" column="0">
                    <widget class="QLabel" name="topology_label">
                     <property name="text">
                      <string>-T --topology</string>
                     </property>
                    </widget>
                   </item>
                   <item row="2" column="0">
                    <widget class="QLineEdit" name="proj_in_input">
                     <property name="placeholderText">
                      <string>EPSG:32632</string>
                     </property>
                    </widget>
                   </item>
                   <item row="16" column="0">
                    <widget class="QLabel" name="label_11">
                     <property name="text">
                      <string>-x, --x-offset</string>
                     </property>
                    </widget>
                   </item>
                   <item row="0" column="0">
                    <widget class="QWidget" name="checkGroup_1" native="true">
                     <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout">
                      <property name="leftMargin">
                       <number>0</number>
                      </property>
                      <property name="topMargin">
                       <number>0</number>
                      </property>
                      <property name="rightMargin">
                       <number>0</number>
                      </property>
                      <property name="bottomMargin">
                       <number>6</number>
                      </property>
                      <item>
                       <widget class="QCheckBox" name="force_2d_checkbox">
                        <property name="text">
                         <string>-2, --force-2d</string>
                        </property>
                       </widget>
                      </item>
                      <item>
                       <widget class="QCheckBox" name="validate_checkbox">
                        <property name="text">
                         <string>-v, --validate</string>
                        </property>
                       </widget>
                      </item>
                      <item>
                       <widget class="QCheckBox" name="english_checkbox">
                        <property name="text">
                         <string>-e, --english</string>
                        </property>
                       </widget>
                      </item>
                      <item>
                       <widget class="QCheckBox" name="strict_checkbox">
                        <property name="text">
                         <string>-c, --strict</string>
                        </property>
                       </widget>
                      </item>
                     </layout>
                    </widget>
                   </item>
                   <item row="11" column="0">
                    <widget class="QLineEdit" name="tolerance_input">
                     <property name="text">
                      <string>0,0</string>
                     </property>
                     <property name="placeholderText">
                      <string>-t, --tolerance (default: 0,0)</string>
                     </property>
                    </widget>
                   </item>
                   <item row="7" column="0">
                    <widget class="QLineEdit" name="orientation_input">
                     <property name="text">
                      <string/>
                     </property>
                     <property name="placeholderText">
                      <string>-O, --orientation (see manual for details)</string>
                     </property>
                    </widget>
                   </item>
                   <item row="1" column="0">
                    <widget class="QLabel" name="label_13">
                     <property name="text">
                      <string>--proj-in</string>
                     </property>
                    </widget>
                   </item>
                  </layout>
                 </widget>
                </item>
               </layout>
              </widget>
             </widget>
            </item>
            <item>
             <widget class="QGroupBox" name="groupBox_5">
              <property name="sizePolicy">
               <sizepolicy hsizetype="Preferred" vsizetype="Expanding">
                <horstretch>0</horstretch>
                <verstretch>0</verstretch>
               </sizepolicy>
              </property>
              <property name="palette">
               <palette>
                <active>
                 <colorrole role="Button">
                  <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
                   <color alpha="255">
                    <red>240</red>
                    <green>184</green>
                    <blue>179</blue>
                   </color>
                  </brush>
                 </colorrole>
                 <colorrole role="Light">
                  <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
                   <color alpha="255">
                    <red>255</red>
                    <green>192</green>
                    <blue>177</blue>
                   </color>
                  </brush>
                 </colorrole>
                </active>
                <inactive>
                 <colorrole role="Button">
                  <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
                   <color alpha="255">
                    <red>240</red>
                    <green>184</green>
                    <blue>179</blue>
                   </color>
                  </brush>
                 </colorrole>
                 <colorrole role="Light">
                  <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
                   <color alpha="255">
                    <red>255</red>
                    <green>192</green>
                    <blue>177</blue>
                   </color>
                  </brush>
                 </colorrole>
                </inactive>
                <disabled>
                 <colorrole role="Button">
                  <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
                   <color alpha="255">
                    <red>240</red>
                    <green>184</green>
                    <blue>179</blue>
                   </color>
                  </brush>
                 </colorrole>
                 <colorrole role="Light">
                  <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
                   <color alpha="255">
                    <red>255</red>
                    <green>192</green>
                    <blue>177</blue>
                   </color>
                  </brush>
                 </colorrole>
                </disabled>
               </palette>
              </property>
              <property name="title">
               <string>Commands</string>
              </property>
              <layout class="QFormLayout" name="formLayout_2"/>
             </widget>
            </item>
           </layout>
          </widget>
         </widget>
        </item>
       </layout>
      </widget>
     </widget>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>


Please provide a MRE

sorry to ask, but what is a MRE?

MRE: [mre], also read [ask]

Thank you. It do not know how I would provide a minimal working example for a QT designer file. Just sharing the ui file?

in this case yes.

@eyllanesc I've updated my question and provided a simple ui file. I'm working on a small mac book, that's why my screnn is limited and the need for scrollbars in QT Designer.

@toni Do not use links to other sites - put the code itself in your question.

@toni  The .ui is an xml, so open it with your IDE and copy the content. Questions should not depend on an external link

@eyllanesc done

Works fine for me on Linux using either Qt-5.15.15 or Qt-6.8.0.

Not working in OSX 5.15.2 :/, will try on Ubuntu … thanks

How is scrolling configured on your macOS? And which version? What if you move the mouse near the right edge and try to scroll?

@toni When you say "not working", does that mean that operating the mouse-wheel (or trackpad) over the area has no effect; or does it simply mean that the scrollbar never shows up during scrolling? Or both? Some widget-styles (such as MacOS) support transient scrollbars, which only appear when you actually start scrolling. However, there have been a few bugs in Qt's implementation of this and it could be you are affected by one of those. Do you see the same behaviour in Qt6 Designer?

Hi @ekhumoro thanks for your answer! The scrollbars are working in my actual application (QGIS) but are not in QT Designer. Here they do not show up, nor has scrolling with mouse or trackpad any effect.

@toni Okay - are you able to test using the latest version of Qt6 Designer? That might help confirm it as a bug in Qt5.

Set the verticalScrollBarPolicy to ScrollBarAlwaysOn
